# Philodandron is slowly yellowing/browning and losing leaves

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-health

Hi fellow plant lovers.

A month ago I got a philodandron and it started losing leaves. It hasn't stopped since then and I'm afraid it's going to die :/

Environment: tropical climate (25C to 28C indoors), fans on and once a day maybe 1h of AC.

It started close to a window, I thought it was yellowing for too much light. I changed it and now it's been 10 days away from the window with artificial light the whole day now.

Evolution:
21st march:
[image: recently arrived at home]

4th April (the day I moved it because it wasn't looking good) 
[image]

20th April (really not looking great) 
[image]

Can anyone give me some tips on how to care for it so it recovers? I'm afraid it's going to die...

Comment: How sure are you that this is a Philodendron (I don't recognise it as a philodendron)? did it come with a label giving  the full name of the plant? And are you saying it now receives no daylight  (not sunlight) at all?

Comment: `How sure are you that this is a Philodendron (I don't recognise it as a philodendron)? did it come with a label giving the full name of the plant?` It did not come with a label, I bought it from a lady who was moving houses. `And are you saying it now receives no daylight (not sunlight) at all?` It is now next to a window with pretty good light, but no direct sunrays