# Philodandron dying - black goo

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, diseases, blight

My philodandron is slowly dying (I created a [previous post here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/51333/philodandron-is-slowly-yellowing-browning-and-losing-leaves), but I lost the access to the account for some reason :/)

In the other post I showed how it went from a nice big plant to losing all its leaves:

a) When we got it
[image]

b) A few weeks later:
[image]

And now it's in a precarious state with only 16 leaves. BUT, we have made a discovery that we couldn't see before: It's got this black goo in the trunk and inside some of fold of the wilted leaves!

[image]

And here more closely:

[image]

I've done a bit of reading and I think it might be a Erwinia Blight? But I know I'm no better than someone googling their own symptoms and thinking that it's surely something terrible... Anyone knows what it could be?

PS: I would like to apologise to user @Bamboo who kindly replied to my old post but I wasn't able to respond due to not being able to access the account.

Comment: You should answer the questions from the comments to your earlier post.

Comment: @Johannes_B good though, but impossible at the moment with the account confusion. Paco, please see [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) how to proceed to have the accounts merged, which will then allow you to access your first post as well, thanks. Once that’s done, I recommend you do some cleanup, please.

Comment: @stephie The OP could answer them here.

Comment: I will merge the accounts and tackle the issue here, as it's more updated. Thanks.

Comment: Answering @Bamboo 's questions here:


`How sure are you that this is a Philodendron (I don't recognise it as a philodendron)? did it come with a label giving the full name of the plant?`

It did not come with a label, I bought it from a lady who was moving houses. 

`And are you saying it now receives no daylight (not sunlight) at all?`

It is now next to a window with pretty good light, but no direct sunrays.